# Как в Webstorm/Phpstorm отправлять локальные файлы на сервер?

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains

У меня есть проект на сервере. Есть полная ее копия на локальной машине.

Есть ли в продуктах jetbrains возможность синхронизировать их по sftp?
В частности, мне нужно, чтобы при сохранении файла на **локальной машине!** он отправлял изменения сразу на сервер. А также мне нужен функционал как Ctrl+Shift+F для сервера.

Мне нужен именно такой способ. Не надо предлагать мне подключаться по sftp, открывать файлы на сервере и менять их.

[Тему](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41650152/search-in-all-project-files-on-remote-host-in-phpstorm) На англоязычном форуме тему видел. Но может у вас есть какие-то другие пути решения.

Comment: Как минимум Ваш вариант не логичен, так как phpstorm сохраняет все в автоматическом режиме, а при такой реализации все что Вы еще не тестировали попадет в продакшен.

Comment: @Дмитрий, автосохранение можно убрать в настройках.

Comment: Даже если убрать все равно Вы же не потестируете код до того как сохраните его.

Comment: @Дмитрий, а как по вашему я сейчас делаю? Мне это и не нужно.

Comment: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Deploying+PHP+applications+with+PhpStorm. Поиск, на удаленной машине работать не будет, сохранение при этом работает. Также появится возможность синхронизации локальная <-> удаленная машина. Если один код будет и на сервере и на локальной машине, в чем смысл поиска на сервере?

Comment: @NikitaR.да, это то, что нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Документация](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Deploying+PHP+applications+with+PhpStorm). 
Поиск, на удаленной машине работать не будет, сохранение при этом работает. Также появится возможность синхронизации локальная <-> удаленная машина. Если один код будет и на сервере и на локальной машине, в чем смысл поиска на сервере?